# Can i set Unique constraints and Not Null constraints to same column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not good in sql. I am just trying to clear my doubts with you. Can i assign two constraints to single column.

e.g

```
     eno ename address mobileno
      1   A      US      9089877878
      2   B      UK      NULL
      3   C      IND     9089877878
```

Consider above example, I don't want to allow user to enter NULL or same value for mobileno column. How can i restrict user to doing this??

Thanks for your important time.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name type NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (column_name))`

Comment: sure :)   But, you have to wait for 10 mins..they are not allowing me to accept answer in first 10 mins..Don't forget about the restriction. :)

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use this way too,

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
Id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is there for both Data can't duplicate as well as Data can't be null.
It is possible using make this column as primary key.

`CREATE TABLE table_name(eno NUMBER(3),ename CHAR(1),address CHAR(3),mobile_no NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY(mobile_no));`

In Oracle we can apply more than one primary key it is know as a composite key in your case it is possible following way:

`CREATE TABLE table_name(eno NUMBER(3),ename CHAR(1),address CHAR(3),mobile_no NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY(eno,mobile_no));`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
 ( eno NUMBER
  ,ename VARCHAR2(100)
  ,address VARCHAR2(2000) 
  ,mobileno NUMBER NOT NULL
  ,constraint table_name_mobile_UK UNIQUE (mobileno)
);
```